# Who decides who can carry out executions of those who mock the Prophet Mohammad?

Tags: sharia, hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation

I have read at [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/86109) and learned that making fun of the Prophet Mohammad is punishable by death. In the Hadith, there are numerous acts carried out by regular people upon those who do so. It came to my attention when hearing about the recent attack on Charlie Hebdo in France. Shouldn't there be guidance on when this decision can be made and who can make it? Or is it up to individuals? This has disturbed me greatly.

Comment: Just a point- the attack had nothing to do with Mohammad. It came after a cartoon of Abu Bakr al-Baghdadi, the leader of Islamic State. However, it is a very valid question and they were previously firebombed in 2011 for drawing Mohammad.

Comment: Muslims cannot implement Hudood (punishments) as they please. Islam is actually an ideology which has law, so law enforcers within a state ([Caliphate] there isn't one at the moment) will execute all laws not just hudood. And of course the suspects have to be tried in court first!

Comment: @Abu Nooh so how should one interpret the Hadith that one did so by themselves without prior consensus of our beloved Prophet Muhammad? Is there Quranic verse that we can refer back to? Jazaklahir!

Comment: @Adam please elaborate on the hadith, I'm not too familiar with what you're saying.

Comment: @Abu Nooh Its in that IsialmicQA post I linked to, I dont feel that much copy and paste is proper so I did not do it.

Comment: @Adam being muslim doesn't give any one the right to be the judge, jury and executioner. All must be tried in court first. As for the ahadith, I'll leave that to qualified Mujtahids to decodify and see the context it was in.

Comment: Just a comment or advice: it is not advisable to execute such harsh Islamic laws out of context. France is not an Islamic state, one cannot implement whatever he/she pleases. One needs to invite people and let them understand the beauty of Islamic world, go through years and years of hard work. Its was not so easy for Muhammad to begin with, and if common sense prevails one needs to understand Muhammad was repeatedly stoned by villagers, he had the power to destroy them, yet he did not.He believed that if any descendants of those villagers comes out as Muslim, it would be an worthwhile effort.

Comment: well it would be worth asking as to can you point us the particular article in IslamQA plz which says "making fun of the Prophet Mohammad is punishable by death"?, so as to get more info from it and can understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

**Ulil Amri , ruler is the one responsible for doing so.**

I ask a simple question, assuming France is not an Islamic country altogether, what if a criminal commits a punishable crime (in an Islamic community) like murder, rape, adultery etc. then **supposing** Some_Country is a completely Islamic country altogether, can these people Some_Country take actions going on in France? Can they punish the criminals in France just because Islam has laws provided for those crimes?

The answer is basically **NO**.

In a community say A, a leader of some other community say B doesn't get to take actions on the people of A. So, in general, only a leader of an Islamic community can take actions only in his community.

Now in our case, if Muslims are a minority in a community say A, then Muslims have to be very careful in that place, abiding by the rules and regulations of that community. This could be considered analogous to Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) dwelling in his community of disbelievers during his early days of Prophet-hood. Imagine, at the very beginning when he was only with a few followers, when he was mocked. Only when a community comes in the hands of Muslims, then the leader of that community gets to rule according to Islamic laws and take actions as deemed necessary for the sake of the community.

So, if in a Muslim community (today), suppose some nonbeliever in it mocks the Prophet (pbuh) by any means, say cartoons, then the leader of that community decides what to do.

Here are some of the main points from [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/86109) article which I found relevant,

- We must denounce it forcefully, each of us according to his abilities, by sending letters and articles, or making phone calls, to their government, foreign affairs departments and newspapers.
- We should demand a clear and sincere apology from them, not deception or justification of the crime which they call an apology. We do not want an apology for showing disrespect towards the Muslims; rather we want an admission of error and an apology for that error.
- We should request them to punish the criminals for their crime.

And so are other points in it.

But, remember, anytime, **what ever step is taken, it is taken wisely, rather than in a rage.**

Comment: edited it, if u find something not good plz feel free to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

There's no Islamic law against those who insult/mock the prophet, the executions that took place in the past was during war time.

Today, most people refer to this Hadith when talking about execution of those who insult/mock the prophet:

> **Volume 5, Book 59, Number 369**

In summary, the Hadith refers to Mohammad's (pbuh) orders to execute a Jewish poet who incited people against Muslim and Islam.

This isn't just an Islamic practice, even America commits such executions, for example the execution of Anwar al Awlaki, who was inciting people against America with his eloquent speech.

**As for who can carry the execution of those who incite violence against Muslim?** Anyone, but the orders must come from Muslim leader.

**NOTE - this is not for mocking or insulting the prophet, this is for inciting hatred and violence against Muslim and Islam.**

Comment: -1 voted, as your answer ack scholarly view, as there are numerous hadith which state that even in normal times people who mocked prophet Muhammad were killed. so we cannot give fatwa based on just one hadith, but all historical contexts. thats why we should give fatwa in light of scholars views, not just based on one hadith

Answer (score -2):

```
                                   بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In regard to your question that asked

> Who decides who can carry out executions of those who mock the Prophet
>   Mohammad?

According to my research, it seems to be related to the Haakim-a-Shar’ or حاکم الشرع (the governor of Shar’ or canon)
And in regard to the Hakim-a-Shar’ it could be said that he is considered as a Mujtahid who has Fatwa based on Shar’ measurements. Then he is able to decide regarding the matter.

**Reference:**

http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/21390

Comment: Given that your reference is apparently Shi'ite, as is the very *concept* of حاکم الشرع, you *really* need to elaborate on why you think this is even *remotely* relevant to understanding a fatwa from IslamQA.

Answer (score -2):

God Almighty is the one who decide to carry out the execution,in the sense of He can send death upon the one who mocks Prophet Muhammad(pbuh). Because mocking any elements of Islam means a disbelief.